# Memory allocation for NSString and NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

I have a doubt when i am creating an object of NSMutableString it's pointing to two separate memory location but when i am using NSString it's pointing to same location. Can any one please explain the logic behind this.

```
 NSMutableString *myString1 = [NSMutableString new];
 NSMutableString *myString2 = [NSMutableString new];
 NSLog(@"%p",myString1);0x00007fe572416da0
 NSLog(@"%p",myString2);0x00007fe5724114a0

NSString *myString3 = [NSString new];
NSString *myString4 = [NSString new];
NSLog(@"%p",myString3);0x10622e470
NSLog(@"%p",myString4);0x10622e470
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, your code is wrong, and it's not formatted.

Comment: Sorry I am a new here. Can you please share the link?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that your second example prints the same value for both pointers.

Comment: Sorry for the typo error in the second part.   

 NSString *myString1 = [NSString new];
 NSString *myString2 = [NSString new];
 NSLog(@"%p",myString1);0x10622e470
 NSLog(@"%p",myString2);0x10622e470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain it based on the memory used. Below I given details about retain count of these variables under non-ARC scenario

```
NSMutableString *myString1 = [NSMutableString new];

NSLog(@"String Retain Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[myString1 retainCount]); //String Retain Count: 1

NSString *myString3 = [NSString new];

NSLog(@"String Retain Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[myString3 retainCount]); //String Retain Count: 18446744073709551615
```

So in the second case it is considering as a constant string. It consider your string as a NSConstantString.

Answer (score 2):

String allocation, like all object allocation, proves costly in both time and memory. The runtime performs some trickery while instantiating string literals to increase performance and decrease memory overhead. To cut down the number of String objects created in the runtime, the `NSString` class keeps a pool of strings. Each time your code create a string literal, the runtime checks the string literal pool first. If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance returns. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object instantiates, then is placed in the pool. Objective-C can make this optimization since strings are immutable and can be shared without fear of data corruption.

In your second code block,

```
NSString *myString1 = [NSString new];
NSString *myString2 = [NSString new];
```

both strings are initialized to empty strings. Hence they return the same reference of those strings from the string pool.

`NSMutableString` doesn't work that way. Runtime doesn't create a pool because these strings are mutable and there is always a fear of data corruption if the strings are mutable. And hence you see different references being printed out.

The point to take out of this example is that always use `NSString` if you don't want the string to change i.e., immutable for performance reasons. Resort to `NSMutableString` only if you want a mutable version of the string.

Comment: What's a JVM doing here?

Comment: I am used to answering this question in the context of Java. Came out of habit. :\ Edited

Comment: You (and the OP) are wrong about the second example.  It happens when people don't post the code they actually tried.  (Or try the code that was actually posted.)

Comment: That's not the point though is it? The OP seems to be have a problem with wrapping head around the concept of string pool which is answered here. No point in proving that the question/answer is wrong (you can always edit the question) once you know what the OP wants to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Because `NSString` is immutable, the class implementation tries to return the same instance whenever possible.
2. Your second example is wrong because you are creating `NSMutableString`s, and the log statements will print different values.

Comment: Sorry for the typo error in adding the second part

 NSString *myString1 = [NSString new];
 NSString *myString2 = [NSString new];
 NSLog(@"%p",myString1);0x10622e470
 NSLog(@"%p",myString2);0x10622e470

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C will always feel free to use the exact same object when you try to create two immutable objects with the same contents. This is just one example. This extends for example to [NSNull null], @YES, @NO, any short immutable strings, empty arrays, identical NSNumbers etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *firstUserName = @"nick";

NSString *secondUserName = @"nick";


if (firstUserName  == secondUserName)
{
   NSLog(@"areEqual");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"areNotEqual");
}
```

the output of it is **areEqual** surprising ?

Here’s why:

Comparing pointer values equates to checking if they point to the same object. Pointers will have the same value if and only if they actually point to the exact same object (whereas pointers to different objects will not have the same value, even if the objects they point to have the same value).